# Unable to destroy session after clicking logout link in codeigniter(facebook integration)

Tags: facebook, codeigniter

Session is not destroying after clicking the logout link on home page. Here is my code

```
 public function login()
        {


                    $config['appId'] = '405802852809513';
                    $appid=$config['appId'];
                    $config['secret'] = 'b873cf1c00e9e1554cb0eede34d252d5';
                    $secret=$config['secret'];
                    $this->load->library('facebook', $config);
                   $user = $this->facebook->getUser();

                    if ($user) {
                    try {
                        $user_profile = $this->facebook->api('/me');  print_r($user_profile);
                    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                        error_log($e);
                        $user = null;
                    }
                    }
                    if ($user) {
                        echo"<br>";
                echo  $data['logoutUrl']=$this->facebook->getLogouturl(array("next"=>site_url('/user/logout')));
                    } else {
                        $scope = array(
                            'scope'         => 'email,offline_access,publish_stream,user_birthday,user_location,user_work_history,user_about_me,user_hometown'
                            );                        
                    $data['loginUrl'] = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl($scope);
                    }    
                    if ($user) {



                        $logoutUrl=$data['logoutUrl'] ;
                         $user_info = array(                   
                   'name'     => $user_profile["name"],
                   'app_id'=>$appid,
                   'secret'=>$secret,
                   'id'      =>$user_profile["id"],
                   'logoutUrl'=> $logoutUrl,

               );
            $this->load->library('session');
            $this->session->set_userdata($user_info); 

                        redirect('user/home')  ;                                  

                    } else {
                         $this->load->view('frm_login',$data);
                    }


        }
```

After filling email and passoward user will be redirect to home page and **home** method will be called

```
public function home(){
        $this->load->library('session');
        $user_info=$this->session->all_userdata();

        if(isset($user_info['name'])){

            $data['name']=$user_info['name'];   
            if(isset($user_info['logoutUrl']))$data['logoutUrl']=$user_info['logoutUrl'];       
            $this->load->view("home",$data);
        }
        else{
            redirect("user/login");
        }
    }
```

And here is the view for my home page

```
<html>
    <body>
    Welcome <?php echo $name;?>
    <?php
    if(isset($logoutUrl))
    {?>
    <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl?>">Fb_Logout</a>

    <?php }
    else
    {?>
    <a href="<?php echo site_url().'/user/logout';?>">Logout</a>    
    <?php 
    }
    ?>


    </body>
    </html>
```

And here is my **logout** for destroying the session but the prob is that session is not destroying. I tried everything to destroythe session but still it exists.
And if I call **user/loggin** in the url then it show my directly the home page with my facebook name displayed on it.If the session is successfully destroyed then it must show the login screen of facebook, but it is not showing that. Please help me out got stucked in this for almost 2 days. Your replies are totally welcome.

```
public function logout(){
  $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->library('facebook', $config);
  $this->session->unset_userdata($user_info);
   $this->facebook->destroysession();
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect("user/login");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know in which `class` do you have your `logout` method. It is a `class` right? (otherwise it would be strange to see the usage of `$this` inside). Do you have a `session` object in that `class`? What `class` does your `session` object have in your `class`? Is the `class` of your `session` object having a `sess_destroy` method? If so, is it `public`? If so, what does it contain? Also, where do you call your `logout()` method? Is it even executed?

These should have been the questions you should have asked yourself.

[This](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) is a reference about how to destroy the session in php.

Comment: Thanks @ Lajos. my problemhas been solved now. Not the session is successfully destroyed. The problem was that i was not passing my App_id.Now I did that and session is now successfullydestroyed.

Comment: Here every thing is goin under user class.

Comment: can you please tell me how can I display user profile image of facebook on the homepage.?

Comment: Put an img to your homepage where you desire it with the URL of http://graph.facebook.com/<facebook username>/picture as src. Example: <img src="http://graph.facebook.com/Lajos.Arpad.35/picture">

Comment: Lajos I tried this but still it is not displaying the image.Here "Picture" means what? Should I have to pass some value into this "picture"??